# How to add common filter for all tomcat instances without editing the individual instances web.xml file

Tags: tomcat, java-melody

Suppose I need to add the following filter mapping to monitor the webapp by javamelody

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <listener>
        <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
```

But I don't want to add the filter into the every tomcat instance web.xml file. Is there any way to achieve this?